# Jest unable to load got libary for testing - 'SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module'

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, jestjs, babel-jest

I have a pretty simple problem but I can't for the life of me figure out how to make it work, I've spent hours looking online..

I'm using the got library to work with a weather API here is the code below:

```html
import got from 'got';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

class WeatherApi {

  #getApiKey = () => process.env.WEATHER_API;
  
  fetchWeatherData = (city, callback) => {
    const apiKey = this.#getApiKey();
    const apiUrl = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?units=metric&q=${city}&appid=${apiKey}`;
    
    got(apiUrl).then((response) => {
      const weatherData = JSON.parse(response.body);
      callback(weatherData)
      });
  }
}

export { WeatherApi }
```

The code works perfectly when I run it with node, however when I try and run tests using **Jest** I get the followig:

```html
  C:\Users\alfon\OneDrive\Documents\Coding\JavaScript\thermostat\node_modules\got\dist\source\index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import create from './create.js';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

    > 1 | import got from 'got';
        | ^
      2 | import dotenv from 'dotenv';
      3 | dotenv.config();
      4 |

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1728:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (weather_api.js:1:1)
```

My issue is that it seems that only the got library has trouble being imported, if I remove it and run Jest dotenv library gets loaded normally. I have no idea what I'm missing here..

Comment: I can also add that if I try and import got directly in my weather.test.js file it also runs the same error.

Comment: Also using axios instead of got resolves any issues.. So not sure what the issue is with got!

Answer (score 3):

I ended up trying an older version of got (11.8.2), which runs ES35 and that gives no problems at all. I'm guessing maybe the newer version of got which came out one month ago is causing some potential issues?

```html
npm install got@11.8.2
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/got

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).